# How do I make Visual Studio better at finding a method overload in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio is terrible at finding an overload that matches parameters as you type them for C#, see below image.

[image: Terrible overload matching]

The image below is the first overload that actually matches the parameter types I've typed, why is the IDE not showing that tooltip instead?

[image: The overload I want]

Is there any way to make the IDE be smarter about this? I know that in VB.NET it actually does this properly, why the difference in C#?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 - no addons (i.e. R#)

Comment: What version of VS?  FWIW, I'm on 2013.  I don't know if that version itself is better, but I have resharper installed, and that combination with your code above shows pretty accurate overloads while I'm typing.  So the answer to your question _"Is there any way to make the IDE be smarter about this?"_ might be: Buy [resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Comment: I'm on 2013 and don't have this problem. (No resharper needed)

Comment: Poor developer without R# here. Using VS2013, I get the same result as the OP

Comment: Also fun fact, typing the second `Rectangle` parameter displays the 9th overload, which requires an array of points as second parameter.

Comment: I'm curious what happens in VS2015, you in a position to try it out?

Comment: @31eee384 I am. Exact same result as with VS 2013.

Comment: @theB are you saying that if you type the exact code in my post that you'll get the 11th overload as your tooltip?

Comment: @test - I must be smoking crack today, either I just hit the down arrow instinctively while typing, or I was dreaming. That said, I'm not really sure that this question is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. If the desire is to improve VS, then it would have to go through [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/).

Comment: It's definitely on-topic. Questions about common developer tools (such as Visual Studio ) are welcome here. There even are tags about all VS versions...